# Screen Space Ambient Obscurance with Orthographic Camera?

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine

It would appear the standard-asset effect [Screen Space Ambient Obscurance](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScreenSpaceAmbientObscurance.html) doesn't work with an Orthographic camera. Its odd because the basic [SSAO](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScreenSpaceAmbientOcclusion.html) script works perfectly fine. I suspect the issue is with a bad calculation of the fragment's depth.

Is there a way to edit the effect to make it work as intended with an orthographic camera?

Comment: if it helps, it seems others managed to fix the "original" shader (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6446#issuecomment-96634340). I attempted to make the same changed, but it didn't work. That said, the Unity shader has been changed from the original.

Comment: What does three.js have to do with unity?

Comment: nothing, but they (appear to) talk about using the original shader (which is generic). That shader has been ported to Unity, but has been changed quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little bit late, but i just faced the same problem, 
here is how to solve:

(Change **ScreenSpaceAmbientObscurance.shader**)

```
float LinearEyeDepthOrth(float z)
{
    // uniform float4 _ProjectionParams;
    // x = 1 or -1 (-1 if porject is flipped)
    // y = near plane
    // z = far plane
    // w = 1/far plane

    // http://www.derschmale.com/2014/03/19/reconstructing-positions-from-the-depth-buffer-pt-2-perspective-and-orthographic-general-case/
    // Z_view = Z_near + Z_ndc(Z_far - Z_near) 
    return _ProjectionParams.y + z * (_ProjectionParams.z - _ProjectionParams.y);
}

float3 ReconstructCSPosition(float2 S, float z)
{
    float linEyeZ = LinearEyeDepthOrth(z);
    //return float3(( ( S.xy * _MainTex_TexelSize.zw) * _ProjInfo.xy + _ProjInfo.zw) * linEyeZ, linEyeZ);
    return float3(( ( S.xy * _MainTex_TexelSize.zw) * _ProjInfo.xy + _ProjInfo.zw), linEyeZ);
    ...
}
```

After this change, it will render correctly in your orthographic camera.